# Is there a way to process the AWT-Queue from own method?

Tags: java, events, awt

I saw a question from somebody who is not able/willing to change a long-running method to return a `Future<Something>` instead of just `<Something>`. Unfortunately, the method gets called also from the AWT-Thread with the known consequences. I've told him, he's doing nonsense, but there might be a possibility. He could start a SwingWorker (or whatever) from inside his method and process the AWT-Queue while waiting till it finishes.

I mean something like

```
public Something aLongRunningMethodCalledFromTheAwtThread() {
    FutureTask<Something> future = new FutureTask<Something>(...);
    EventQueue eventQueue = Toolkit.getEventQueue();
    while (true) {
        if (future.isDone()) return future.get();
        AWTEvent event = eventQueue.getCurrentEvent();
        if (event==null) {
            waitForAWhile();
        } else {
            eventQueue.pop(); // <---- is protected
            process(event); // <---- BUT HOW???
        }
    }
}
```

AFAIK, such things get done in other frameworks, I wonder if this is possible in Swing/AWT too?

Answer (score 0):

There's no point in implementing an upside solution when a right-side-up solution already exists. The method needs to be executed as a separate thread. Period.

Comment: +1 Would the recalcitrant rascal consider a [continuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation_passing_style#Continuations_as_objects)?

Comment: That's about what *I wrote* I told him, too, so you gave me no information. Period.

Comment: @trashgod I don't think so, either he keeps misunderstanding AWT or he's learned it from another framework.

Comment: @maaartinus: Sorry, I didn't mean to cloud the issue. I'm afraid EJP is right. I was hoping your obstinate colleague might accept the continuation-passing style as sufficiently novel to merit attention.

Comment: No problem, continuations are fun.